# Text wrapping using PHPexcel in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, phpexcel, export-to-excel

i'm using PHPexcel with CodeIgniter, the export file already worked fine but how to make the cell text-wrap ?
here is my code:

```
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('A6:A8')->setCellValue('A6','No');
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('B6:B8')->setCellValue('B6','Sample Code');
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('C6:C8')->setCellValue('C6','Production (BBD/Expiry Date')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('D6:F6')->setCellValue('D6','Analysis');
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('G6:G8')->setCellValue('G6','pH');
```

I've tried to add **getAlignment()->setWrapText(true)** at the end of **C6:C8** setCellValue but it doesn't work, did i use wrong code ?

Answer (score 0):

Alignment is a style property of the cell; you need to get the style for that cell before you can get the alignment from that style.

Assuming that your $objPHPExcel is actually a worksheet rather than the entire workbook (otherwise you should be getting a mass of errors)

```
$objPHPExcel->mergeCells('C6:C8')
    ->setCellValue('C6','Production (BBD/Expiry Date')
    ->getStyle()
    ->getAlignment()
    ->setWrapText(true);
```